# Error while performing python try-except part

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python number guessing game.

```
from random import randint

ran_no = randint(1,10)
print(ran_no)#for checking the output


try:
    guess = int(input('\nYour guess between 1 to 10:- '))
except ValueError:
    print("\n\tPlease enter numbers only\n")
    quit

if type(guess) == int:
    if guess == ran_no:
        print("\n\t\tWhola, Your guess is correct!\n")
    elif guess > 10:
        print("\n\t\tUghh, Your guess is above limit!\n")
    elif guess < 1:
        print("\n\t\tUghh, Your guess is below limit!\n")
    else:
        print("\n\t\tUghh, Try again...\n")
else:
    print("\n\tPlease enter numbers only\n")
```

When i use try-except when except condition occurs i don't know know how should i end code, please help

Comment: What do you want to do when there is a `ValueError`? Exit program or let the user try again?

Comment: How would you expect `if type(guess) == int:` to be `False` if you convert it to an integer before you do the test? Of course you still have an error in your error handling: `quit` achieves nothing.

Comment: I found out the answer i need. 1 - I wanted to quit the program. , 2 - I figured out why i wrote that way. It is what it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need to add () after quit

```
from random import randint

ran_no = randint(1,10)
print(ran_no)#for checking the output


try:
    guess = int(input('\nYour guess between 1 to 10:- '))
except ValueError:
    print("\n\tPlease enter numbers only\n")
    quit()

if type(guess) == int:
    if guess == ran_no:
        print("\n\t\tWhola, Your guess is correct!\n")
    elif guess > 10:
        print("\n\t\tUghh, Your guess is above limit!\n")
    elif guess < 1:
        print("\n\t\tUghh, Your guess is below limit!\n")
    else:
        print("\n\t\tUghh, Try again...\n")
else:
    print("\n\tPlease enter numbers only\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use "exit(0)" instead of quit

Comment: glad it helped. could you accept to the answer please ?

Comment: But in my code, I use quit(). And I already accept another answer. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
from random import randint

ran_no = randint(1,10)
print(ran_no)#for checking the output


try:
    guess = input('\nYour guess between 1 to 10:- ')
    if type(int(guess)) == int:
        guess =(int(guess)) 
        if guess == ran_no:
            print("\n\t\tWhola, Your guess is correct!\n")
        elif guess > 10:
            print("\n\t\tUghh, Your guess is above limit!\n")
        elif guess < 1:
            print("\n\t\tUghh, Your guess is below limit!\n")
        else:
            print("\n\t\tUghh, Try again...\n")
    else:
        print("\n\tPlease enter numbers only\n")
except ValueError:
    print("\n\tPlease enter numbers only\n")
    quit()
```

Sample output 1:

[image]

Sample output 2:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping